# Customize Raphael JS for chart to display different tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, raphael

I have create a chart to display the visits to a webpage. I have everything working, but I want to change the tooltip the appears when you mouse over one of the circles of data.

I am using Raphael JS and built it of of this:
http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/php-visitor-tracking-script-with-jquery-and-raphael-javascript-library

If you click on the link above and scroll down to the bottom of the page this is how my chart works. Mouse over one of the circles and you will notice that it displays the data in a box. I want to add an arrow to the box like a bootstrap tooltip for example.

If you look here:
http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html
and mouse over one of the circles you will see the difference. This is what I want.

To view the code plese click the first link and take a look at the `PHP Class (class.logger.php)` section and look for the `function loadraphael` in the code. This is what I assume I need to customize, but not sure what to change. Any help with examples would be greatly appreciated.

If you need more info from me, let me know.

EDIT: here is the code. You will notice I changed rect to path. Not sure what else I should change.

```
//raphael.path.methods.js
Raphael.el.isAbsolute = true;
Raphael.el.absolutely = function () {
    this.isAbsolute = 1;
    return this;
};
Raphael.el.relatively = function () {
    this.isAbsolute = 0;
    return this;
};
Raphael.el.moveTo = function (x, y) {
    this._last = {x: x, y: y};
    return this.attr({path: this.attrs.path + ["m", "M"][+this.isAbsolute] + parseFloat(x) + " " + parseFloat(y)});
};
Raphael.el.lineTo = function (x, y) {
    this._last = {x: x, y: y};
    return this.attr({path: this.attrs.path + ["l", "L"][+this.isAbsolute] + parseFloat(x) + " " + parseFloat(y)});
};
Raphael.el.arcTo = function (rx, ry, large_arc_flag, sweep_flag, x, y, angle) {
    this._last = {x: x, y: y};
    return this.attr({path: this.attrs.path + ["a", "A"][+this.isAbsolute] + [parseFloat(rx), parseFloat(ry), +angle, large_arc_flag, sweep_flag, parseFloat(x), parseFloat(y)].join(" ")});
};
Raphael.el.curveTo = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0, arguments.length),
        d = [0, 0, 0, 0, "s", 0, "c"][args.length] || "";
    this.isAbsolute && (d = d.toUpperCase());
    this._last = {x: args[args.length - 2], y: args[args.length - 1]};
    return this.attr({path: this.attrs.path + d + args});
};
Raphael.el.cplineTo = function (x, y, w) {
    this.attr({path: this.attrs.path + ["C", this._last.x + w, this._last.y, x - w, y, x, y]});
    this._last = {x: x, y: y};
    return this;
};
Raphael.el.qcurveTo = function () {
    var d = [0, 1, "t", 3, "q"][arguments.length],
        args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0, arguments.length);
    if (this.isAbsolute) {
        d = d.toUpperCase();
    }
    this._last = {x: args[args.length - 2], y: args[args.length - 1]};
    return this.attr({path: this.attrs.path + d + args});
};
Raphael.el.addRoundedCorner = function (r, dir) {
    var rollback = this.isAbsolute;
    rollback && this.relatively();
    this._last = {x: r * (!!(dir.indexOf("r") + 1) * 2 - 1), y: r * (!!(dir.indexOf("d") + 1) * 2 - 1)};
    this.arcTo(r, r, 0, {"lu": 1, "rd": 1, "ur": 1, "dl": 1}[dir] || 0, this._last.x, this._last.y);
    rollback && this.absolutely();
    return this;
};
Raphael.el.andClose = function () {
    return this.attr({path: this.attrs.path + "z"});
};


//raphael analytics
Raphael.fn.drawGrid = function (x, y, w, h, wv, hv, color) {
color = color || "'.$fillcolor.'";
var path = ["M", x, y, "L", x + w, y, x + w, y + h, x, y + h, x, y],
    rowHeight = h / hv,
    columnWidth = w / wv;
for (var i = 1; i < hv; i++) {
    path = path.concat(["M", x, y + i * rowHeight, "L", x + w, y + i * rowHeight]);
}
for (var i = 1; i < wv; i++) {
    path = path.concat(["M", x + i * columnWidth, y, "L", x + i * columnWidth, y + h]);
}
return this.path(path.join(",")).attr({stroke: color});
};
$(function () {
    $(".'.$tableid.'").css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: "-9999em",
        top: "-9999em"
    });
});
window.onload = function () {
// Grab the data
var labels = [],
    data = [];
$(".'.$tableid.' tfoot th").each(function () {
    labels.push($(this).html());
});
$(".'.$tableid.' tbody td").each(function () {
    data.push($(this).html());
});

// Draw
var width = '.$width.',
    height = '.$height.',
    leftgutter = '.$leftgutter.',
    bottomgutter = '.$bottomgutter.',
    topgutter = '.$topgutter.',
    colorhue = .6 || Math.random(),
    color = "hsb(" + [colorhue, 1, .75] + ")",
    r = Raphael("'.$div.'", width, height),
    txt = {font: \'12px Fontin-Sans, Arial\', fill: "'.$fontcolor.'"},
    txt1 = {font: \'10px Fontin-Sans, Arial\', fill: "'.$fontcolor.'"},
    txt2 = {font: \'12px Fontin-Sans, Arial\', fill: "'.$fontcolor.'"},
    X = (width - leftgutter) / labels.length,
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, data),
    Y = (height - bottomgutter - topgutter) / max;
r.drawGrid(leftgutter + X * .5, topgutter, width - leftgutter - X, height - topgutter - bottomgutter, 10, 10, "'.$gridcolor.'");
var path = r.path().attr({stroke: "'.$strokecolor.'", "stroke-width": 4, "stroke-linejoin": "round"}),
    bgp = r.path().attr({stroke: "'.$strokecolor.'", opacity: .3, fill: "'.$fillcolor.'"}).moveTo(leftgutter + X * .5, height - bottomgutter),
    frame = r.path("M25,15 q 0,-5 5,-5 l 90,0 q 5,0 5,5 l 0,30 q 0,5 -5,5 l -90,0 q -5,0 -5,-5 l 0,-5 -14.1,-10 14.1,-10z").attr({fill: "'.$datafillcolor.'", stroke: "'.$datastrokecolor.'", "stroke-width": 2}).hide(),
    label = [],
    is_label_visible = false,
    leave_timer,
    blanket = r.set();
label[0] = r.text(60, 10, "24 hits").attr(txt).hide();
label[1] = r.text(60, 40, "22 September 2008").attr(txt1).attr({fill: "'.$fontcolor.'"}).hide();
for (var i = 0, ii = labels.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var y = Math.round(height - bottomgutter - Y * data[i]),
        x = Math.round(leftgutter + X * (i + .5)),
        t = r.text(x, height - 6, labels[i]).attr(txt).toBack();
    bgp[i == 0 ? "lineTo" : "cplineTo"](x, y, 10);
    path[i == 0 ? "moveTo" : "cplineTo"](x, y, 10);
    var dot = r.circle(x, y, 5).attr({fill: "'.$dotfillcolor.'", stroke: "'.$dotstrokecolor.'", "stroke-width": 2});
    blanket.push(r.rect(leftgutter + X * i, 0, X, height - bottomgutter).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "'.$fontcolor.'", opacity: 0}));
    var rect = blanket[blanket.length - 1];
    (function (x, y, data, lbl, dot) {
        var timer, i = 0;
        $(rect.node).hover(function () {
            clearTimeout(leave_timer);
            var newcoord = {x: +x + 7.5, y: y - 19};
            if (newcoord.x + 100 > width) {
                newcoord.x -= 114;
            }
            frame.show().animate({x: newcoord.x, y: newcoord.y}, 200 * is_label_visible);
            label[0].attr({text: data + " hit" + ((data % 10 == 1) ? "" : "s")}).show().animateWith(frame, {x: +newcoord.x + 50, y: +newcoord.y + 12}, 200 * is_label_visible);
            label[1].attr({text: lbl + " '.$month_year.'"}).show().animateWith(frame, {x: +newcoord.x + 50, y: +newcoord.y + 27}, 200 * is_label_visible);
            dot.attr("r", 7);
            is_label_visible = true;
        }, function () {
            dot.attr("r", 5);
            leave_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                frame.hide();
                label[0].hide();
                label[1].hide();
                is_label_visible = false;
                // r.safari();
            }, 1);
        });
    })(x, y, data[i], labels[i], dot);
}
bgp.lineTo(x, height - bottomgutter).andClose();
frame.toFront();
label[0].toFront();
label[1].toFront();
blanket.toFront();
};
```

Comment: Look inside the popup.js file on the raphaeljs.com example, the shape you are looking for is defined by a complex set of variables: shapes, offset, mask, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I tried looking into it, but I was unable to get it to work and without any guidance I don't know if I will be able to figure it out. It seems like very complicated code and I'm not that familiar with JS on this level. Thanks again.

Comment: cross looking at the code of emirplicanic.com, you should change the frame element from rect to path and draw it with the expected arrow, something like: "M25,15 q 0,-5 5,-5 l 90,0 q 5,0 5,5 l 0,30 q 0,5 -5,5 l -90,0 q -5,0 -5,-5 l 0,-5 -14.1,-10 14.1,-10z" (this is relative to the rectangle)

Comment: @crockz That worked! but the one problem I have is it is always displayed in the upper left hand corner of the chart. How do I make it appear next to each circle when I mouse over?

Comment: Can you post your code, or make a fiddle without php, I can get into it but I need a little bit more.

Comment: @crockz Having trouble with JSfiddle, but added my code above. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Sorry for misguiding you to try to change the code before. The code you posted looks very similar to raphaeljs.com code, so why don't you use it just as it is. Use php to populate the table and just change the colors, width, height, etc... see it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/gh97j6z3/1/). I can add comments explaining every part of it, if you need.

Comment: @crockz thanks again. I tried using the code in your JSFiddle which is similar code in the raphael example, but it does not display any data on my chart because of the way it was originally written I think. I have compared my file against yours and there are many differences and I'm not sure what to change. I will give it another shot.

Comment: @crockz if you take a look at this image - http://oi61.tinypic.com/2a6o0uc.jpg you will see that the data is being loaded but the chart is not displaying. Please let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: @crockz sorry for all the comments, but i made a mistake in my code and now everything works now. Thank you so much for your help. How do I give you credit for the answer?

Comment: @crockz Also, would you know how I add a second line for other data on the same chart?